# TFS Test Hub - Requirements-Based Suite not updating count

Tags: testing, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

Test cases are created in iterations with our sprint cycles. They are then added to a test plan via requirements-based query for our integration and system testing.

At the end of every sprint and leading up to integration and system testing, the requirements-based query is run repeatedly against the same same static test suite to add any newly created test cases to the test plan.

The requirements-based query will see the new items and add them to the test plan, however, anywhere that displays the total count of test cases in the test plan or suites does not update automatically. This includes counts shown in TFS web GUI ("Show count from child tests"), MTM, and any dashboard charts.

The only way to get that count to update is to manually click on each test suite generated from the requirements-based suite.

---

Repro Steps:

1. Create Test Plan - "Test Plan A"
2. Create Static Suite in newly created Test Plan - "Static Suite B"
3. Right click on "Static Suite B" and select "New requirements-based suite"
4. Fill out criteria for requirements-based suite. My query: Top Level: 'Work Item Type - In Group - Feature/Requirement/Bug Categories' and 'Release Number = XX.XX'. Linked Work Items: 'Work Item Type = Test Case'. 'Return all top level items' is selected.
5. Run query. Results display in grid, including top level items that do not yet have test cases but are assigned to upcoming release.
6. Select all results in the grid.
7. Select "Create Suites". Suites are created for all items included in the release, including items that do not yet have test cases. Note the total count of test cases in "Static Suite B". This count will display in any charts for this test plan and/or suite.
8. Add a test case for an item that is included in the release but did not have a test case during prior step. Note the top level item for upcoming step.
9. Navigate back to "Test Plan A".
10. Right click on "Static Suite B" and select "New requirements-based suite"
11. Query used in Step 4 displays. Do not make any changes to the query.
12. Run query again. Results display in grid for all top level items, including those that do not yet have test cases but are assigned to upcoming release. Newly created test case should display in the results.
13. Select all results and select "Create Suites". No new suites are created since they were created in Step 6 above. **Do not select existing requirements based suite for the test case that was added in Step 8.**
14. Check the total count of test cases in "Static Suite B" and any test plan/suite charts. Observe count has not incremented per new test case.
15. Navigate to "Static Suite B" and select the requirements-based suite where test case was added in Step 7. Observe test case displays in the requirements-based suite as expected.
16. Check the total count of test cases in "Static Suite B" and any test plan/suite charts. Observe count is not incremented per new test case.

[Screenshot of requirements-based query and results (obfuscated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKbpT.png)

### [Screenshot of counts that do not update (obfuscated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FELAM.png)

Has anyone else encountered this and have a fix/work-around?

Using local TFS Version 16.122.27102.1.

Comment: Could you please provide detailed steps here to reproduce your scenario?

Comment: Is `Release Number` a custom field? Are you able to see the newly added test cases in step 12? You said "Newly created test case should display in the results", do you mean you can't see the newly added test cases? Also, if you only select the newly created test case and select "Create Suites" in Step 13, what result will you get?

Comment: Yes, Release Number is a custom field.
When I re-run the query in step 12, the newly added test cases **do display** in the results. They don't display in the requirements-based suite immediately after selecting "Create Suites".
If I only select the newly created test case and select "Create Suites" = same result. New test case doesn't display immediately.

My problem seems to be that once the requirements-based suites are created, if any new test cases are added to any of the items the suites are linked to, the count is not updated until I manually click on the requirements-based suite.

Comment: Since your query is "Top Level: 'Work Item Type - In Group - Feature/Requirement/Bug Categories' and 'Release Number = XX.XX'. Linked Work Items: 'Work Item Type = Test Case'. 'Return all top level items' is selected." And the test cases work items is not belonging to Microsoft.RequirementCategory, how did you select it and create suite? Could you share a screenshot of your query result?

Comment: Screenshot of query result added. The problem is not the items returning in the query, that is always correct. It is when the suite is created before tests are added, the suite counts are not updated until the suite is clicked on, which basically triggers a refresh and it realized new tests are there. When this affects just one suite it isn't an issue, but when there are 500+ items in a release and the suites are created early, clicking through each one is a waste of time.

Comment: Yes, query returns correct result. But from my test, the test cases are not able to be selected to create suite, as when try to create suite for the test cases, it will give error message "You should select at least one work item belonging to Microsoft.RequirementCategory."

Comment: "6. Select all results in the grid."  Every time I re-run the query I select everything in the grid. I have to do this because new requirements (Features and/or PBIs) are added and I need those new suites to be created, and new test cases are added to suites that are already existing.

Comment: Select all results in the grid won't give any error, but the test cases won't be added to the test suite. How did you add the test cases?

Comment: Test cases are added to the work item (Feature or PBI) from the Kanban board.
Following the steps above, the test cases are added to the test suite, it's just that the count on all of the charts on my dashboards will not update until I manually click on the suite-- this apparently causes a refresh and the counts are then updated.

Comment: Could you also provide a screenshot of the count?

Comment: I edited original post to include screenshot of counts that do not update automatically when new test cases are added.

Comment: I tried that first, a simple refresh doesn't do it. The charts are used on dashboards across multiple projects, so I'm not sure if that is a contributing factor. We just updated to TFS 2018.2 (Version 16.131.27701.1) a week ago so I will test to see if this has been corrected.

Comment: I just tried that and no luck. I had one requirements based suite with 1 test case. I added 4 more test cases to the Bug, refreshed the browser tab with the Test Plan and it did not update the count. I did a soft and hard refresh of the browser tab... still nothing. I then clicked on the test suite, it refreshed the suite and saw the new test cases, then I did a browser tab refresh and everything was updated.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue on my side, maybe it's because you have lots test suites cause the count refresh slow. You may create a new test plan and add few test suites to see whether you can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yeah, no luck, thanks Cece.
For now I will only be creating test suites for items that have test cases in order to try and maintain this... but it's definitely a nightmare when we have lots of items and our dashboards aren't updating correctly.

Comment: Yes! That is my problem. In order for testing to move forward, test plans are created in advance and tests executed throughout the lifecycle... which leaves me manually selecting each test suite every morning to update what was done the prior day. It's a lot of manual work and frustrating.